# How to merge colums of multiple text files into one csv file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have got multiple measurement files with one column of numeric data each. (*Update*: The script should work for variable numbers of measurement files.)

**data1.dat**

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
```

**data2.dat**

```
10.0
20.0
30.0
```

...

**dataN.dat**

```
1
1
1
```

How can I merge these data files into a comma separated values file using **Powershell**?

```
"data1","data2.dat",...,"dataN.dat"
1.0,10.0,...,1
2.0,20.0,...,1
3.0,30.0,...,1
```

**Related**

- [Merging Two Text Files into One CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672600/merging-two-text-files-into-one-csv-file) does not help my case, but might help other people who search for column merging.
- [Powershell / Perl : Merging multiple CSV files into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988518/powershell-perl-merging-multiple-csv-files-into-one) is similar but there the lines have an id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem D:\temp *.dat
$header = $files|foreach {$_.basename}
$content= $files | foreach { ,(gc $_.fullname) }

$lines = for($i=0; $i -lt $content[0].Count; $i++)
{
    $line = for($x=0; $x -lt $files.count; $x++)
    {
        $content[$x][$i]        
    }

    $line -join ','
}

$lines | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $header | Export-Csv data.csv
```

Comment: Can you please explain the comma in `foreach { ,(gc $_.fullname) }`?

Comment: sure, the comma operator is the array construction operator in PowerShell. It creates a one element array and puts the result in the first element. Without it, all lines of all files would assign to $content. Remove it and print $content, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138288/how-to-create-array-of-arrays-in-powershell which I want to share.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$file1 = "C:\firstTxtFile.txt"
$file2 = "C:\SecondTxtFile.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\Output.txt"

$file1String = Get-content $file1 
$file2String = Get-content $file2

'"data1.dat","data2.dat"' > $outputFile

$counter = 0
while(($file1String[$counter] -ne $null) -and ($file2String[$counter] -ne $null)){
    $Line = $file1String[$counter] + "," + $file2String[$counter]
    $line >> $outputFile
    $counter++
}
```

This will take two text file and combine them into one output file.

**Note**: The output file will be overwritten each time this is run.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question to clarify that the script needs to process a varying number of files, not a fixed number.